# is there a suitelet script to upload the files by drag and drop to the file cabinet in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, netsuite-rest-api

suitelet script should be able to upload the files using drag and drop

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/file'], function(serverWidget, file) {

  function onRequest(context) {
    if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
      // Create the form
      var form = serverWidget.createForm({
        title: 'Drag and Drop Files'
      });

      // Add a drop zone to the form
      var dropZoneField = form.addField({
        id: 'custpage_dropzone',
        type: serverWidget.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
        label: 'Drag and Drop Files Here'
      });

      // Set up the drop zone HTML
      var dropZoneHTML = '<div id="dropZone" style="border: 2px dashed #ccc; padding: 20px; text-align: center;">' +
        '<span style="font-size: 18px;">Drag and Drop Files Here</span>' +
        '</div>';
      dropZoneField.defaultValue = dropZoneHTML;

      // Add a hidden field to store the file ID
      var fileIdField = form.addField({
        id: 'custpage_fileid',
        type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
        label: 'File ID'
      });
      fileIdField.updateDisplayType({
        displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
      });

      // Add a submit button to the form
      form.addSubmitButton({
        label: 'Upload'
      });

      // Render the form
      context.response.writePage(form);
    } else if (context.request.method === 'POST') {
      // Handle the file upload
      var fileObj = file.create({
        name: context.request.files.custpage_file.name,
        fileType: context.request.files.custpage_file.fileType,
        contents: context.request.files.custpage_file.getContents(),
        folder: 12807 // Specify the folder ID where you want to save the file
      });
      var fileId = fileObj.save();

      // Redirect to the File Cabinet
      context.response.sendRedirect({
        type: serverWidget.RedirectType.MEDIA_ITEM,
        identifier: fileId
      });
    }
  }

  return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  };
});
```

Comment: That's a statement, not a question. Please edit what you've posted to provide some useful information, and a description of what you've tried. Remember that SO is here to help you to debug code, not to write it for you

Comment: Also there is a free drag and drop suite bundle, 41309 that may do all that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand what you want as I see no question but you can make your own suitelet with inlinehtml field , and do your one custom HTML drag and drop field there . You can also attach a client script for the event listeners if u like